# Searching MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter + MySQL.

I am succeeding in running this query and parsing the result.

```
$var1 = $this->db->query("select title from stores where title like \"" . $str . "%\" union select title from coupons where title like \"" . $str . "%\"");
return $var1;
```

And in the controller, I parse the `result()` of this query to a JSON file using `json_encode`

But when I run the same query on another table, and follow the same step in parsing, I am facing parsing problems.

```
$var1 = $this->db->query("select tagword from tags where tagword like \"" . $str ."%\"");
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `$var1 = $this->db->query("select tagword from tags where tagword like \"" . $str ."%\""); return $var1;` missing the return value

Comment: I just forgot to include the return statement for the problematic query. I have it in my code. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: are you sure that parsing error occurs in this line? Your query seems ok to me there is no syntax error in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo-ing your SQL Statement

```
echo  $this->db->last_query();
```

Then try Run SQL query/queries on your database for your debugging purpose